# Remove selected CMS block in custom widget Magento2

Tags: magento2, widget

I have doubts in Magento2 widget.
In my custom widget I have added the CMS block through chooser then saved successfully.
When I come to edit, I need to remove the selected cms block in the widget.

How can I remove the selected cms block?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default magento2 have no remove button, so you need to do some work around for this.

You can create new class which is extended by CMS block chooser class (`Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Chooser`).

```
namespace Sathish\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Widget;

class Chooser extends Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Chooser
{

/**
     * Prepare chooser element HTML
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
    $uniqId = $this->mathRandom->getUniqueHash($element->getId());
        ................
        ................

    $html = $chooser->toHtml();
        $html .= '<span class="action-default scalable btn-chooser" onClick="jQuery(\'#'.$uniqId.'label\').text(\'Not Selected\');jQuery(\'#'.$uniqId.'value\').val(\'\');">Remove</span>';
        $element->setData('after_element_html', $html);
        return $element;
    }
}
```

here you can able to get the unique id of block.

- for selected block label magento used this format for Id: `unique id + 'label'`
- for selected block value magento used this format for Id: `unique id + 'value'`

then append some button including js snippets in existing prepared HTML like above said.

I hope this will help you to achieve your goal.
thanks.

Comment: It works for me.